# YAML parsing vs Database

Tags: php, yaml

I'm making simple web application for my friend but he want to have "friendly links" so I have create simple Router. My quesion is what is better and faster - create YAML file with paths and parse it using YAML parser from Symfony or create table in database with paths and get them by query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML files will be parsed into PHP files.
On the other hand SQL database storage is more extendable.

Depends on how your application will handle the paths and also how many records will be in the storage.

If the amount of paths is between 10-100 use YAML - more than that use SQL database.